# How to create an Xcode archive from a Flutter macos build?

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos

Everything is in the title, i have built my app using `flutter build macos --release` and the output structure is like : `macos -> Build -> Products -> Release -> all_plugins_and_app_directories`

I would like to know how can i create an Xcode archive from the content of `macos/Build/Products/Release` please ?

EDIT : My goal is to upload a macos build from Flutter to App Store connect from Xcode as the `Product -> Archive` command does.

EDIT 2 : Flutter documentation says :

[image]

Step 2 is wrong because it creates a new archive -> documentation is incomplete please see my github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/9046)

Comment: if you had gone through the Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos

Comment: Let me update the question to show you why it doesn't answer the question, otherwise i would not have asked it

Comment: you should have added all the details while posting the question. :)

Comment: Sorry you are right, i assumed it was obvious that some research are made before asking questions here

Comment: "Step 2 is wrong because it creates a new archive" Yes, that's pretty silly. But it is also obvious how to access a previously built archive.

Comment: My underneath goal is to upload an obfuscated build to app store connect without using CodeMagic, so i want to create a new xcode archive from the flutter build in the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/` to open it with the Organizer and submit it as usual

Comment: Because i am not confident in my workaround for the long run, meaning building 2 apps and replacing the runner app of the non obfuscated built archive from Xcode `Product->Archive` by the obfuscated one from flutter. It's working so far but...